# Count the number of occurences of a string in a file in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk

I have a .TXT file in UNIX with 1 million records in it which is a Pipe delimited, i would like to count the number of occurences of '|' in the 2nd record.
Can someone please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add (a part of) your input and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==2{print NF-1; exit}' file
```

split the record with the defined field separator, the count of separators is one less than the number of fields

or

```
$ awk 'NR==2{print gsub("\\|","|")}' file
```

replace all occurrences of `|` and print the count.  Since `|` is a special regex character you need to escape it (and escape the escape char as well).